# Odoo Cron task to start PoS

Tags: cron, task, odoo, point-of-sale

Is there a way to start the point of sale from a cron task/job.
I'd like to start the Point_of_sale every morning, so the loading is finished by the time the store opens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easy solution is: don't close it the previuos day, just suspend the computer

Answer (score 0):

Use this module if you just want to speed up pos load time

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/pos_cache/

**Note** Just update your cache when you make change product price